# protect mysql data folder in Windows 7

Tags: mysql, windows-7

This question is in reference with the question - 
[How To Protect Database Files From Copying In Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21969792/how-to-protect-database-files-from-copying-in-windows)

I have stored the database in a computer not connected through internet and provided to the user. The database is used by an application which i have written.

The user who logs in to computer is an adminstrator level user in Windows OS .So he can read/write copy files without any restrictions.
The user accesses database thorugh an application with a fixed password known by the application.

As i have confidential information in the database which i do not want the user to access, i would like to restrict the computer owners access to database.

The user can still copy database files and view database in another system with out knowing mysql password.

I have tried to encrypt Drive using Bit Locker software but as soon as i copy the file in other hard drive/USB media i can see it in plaintext on USB media.

Are there any tools available to prevent users from  copying the database files while still allowing applications to access or write data to database.

Comment: Your question is somewhat paradoxical, as you're kind-of asking how to make an admin not an admin. You could store them on an encrypted drive/partition or run the server on a machine only trusted people have access to.

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara, I have updated the question. Hope i am more clear about what i wanted to ask.

Comment: This is impossible. If the user has physical (administrator) access to the database  (file system) there is no way you can protect the data.